# Is keyPressed being activated correctly?

Tags: file-io, arduino, processing

I was introduced to Processing to acquire data from my Arduino about 5 hours ago. It seems to make sense to me, and I've had no previous java experience, but am familiar (but still quite shaky) with C, C+, and Matlab, so nothing out of the blue. I put together my code based on a lot of other code (one method I compared to was [here (official site)](https://processing.org/reference/createWriter_.html) and [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/saving-arduino-output-to-a-text-file-in-append-mode)), and it seems to be spot on.

My problem is that the file Processing creates is empty. Additionally, the file is created just before the Arduino's data starts showing up in the console. So I'm wondering why the file is created but never actually altered? I understand maybe the file is empty while Processing is running, but when I hit the stop button, I would expect that keyPressed would be called, per Processing's definition of createWriter (previously linked).

```java
import processing.serial.*;

// Dynamic constants
String portNum = "COM4";  // Choose COM port -- will vary by computer
String FileName = "test.txt";  // Name will change for data collection

// Static constants
Serial myPort;    // Create object from Serial class
String val;       // Data received from the serial port
PrintWriter output;

void setup() {
  //String portName = Serial.list()[portNum];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portNum, 9600);
  output = createWriter(FileName);
}

void draw() {
  if (myPort.available() > 0) {          // If data is available,
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');  // read it and store it in val
  } 
  if (val != null) {     // For valid data
    output.println(val); // print data
    println(val);        // To see it's working
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
output.flush(); // Writes the remaining data to the file
output.close(); // Finishes the file
exit();         // Stops the program
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I hit the stop button, I would expect that keyPressed would be called

This is not how the `keyPressed()` function works. The `keyPressed()` function fires when you press a key on the keyboard. It does not fire when you press the stop button.

Try clicking in your sketch window (in the window that pops up, not the editor) and then pressing a key on your keyboard.

If that doesn't do what you expected, then it sounds like some [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) is in your future. Is the `draw()` function doing what you expected? Is the `val` variable printing what you'd expect? If you add a `println()` statement inside the `keyPressed()` function, does it print out?

Try to start with a simpler example. Get rid of the arduino stuff and just output a hard-coded file. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific question. Good luck!

Comment: To address your questions:
* I have tried clicking on the sketch window, and wailing upon my keyboard.
*val shows up just fine, as I expect.
*Not sure what you mean by adding a println() in keyPressed()? What should I print there?
*I actually created Arduino code to ensure I can export data. I see the data in Processing, but my file is still empty. I'm not sure how my code is "excessive" and not minimal?

Comment: @Asinine Where did I say your code was excessive? I suggested adding a `println()` statement inside the `keyPressed()` function just to confirm it's firing at all. Again, I recommend starting with something simpler: can you create a sketch that stores the user's mouse locations inside a file when the user presses a key? If you post that sketch, it'll be much easier to help you. Good luck.

Comment: I assumed the Arduino input was excessive @Kevin Workman.

I'm not sure what the issue was, but on my desktop now and I see the square. Clicking that then pushing a button stops the program and writes the file. 

Thank you for the reply; I'd searched all over but I guess I had to try on another computer. Now to debug my Surface.